# Strange error on query.findInBackground

Tags: android, parse-platform

Code:

```
@Override
public void fetchMyRides(final ArrayList<RideModel> listOfRides) {
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseQuery<RideModel> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(RideModel.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("userObjectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<RideModel>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<RideModel> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) 
                 {
                  if (objects.size() > 0) 
                    {
                      listOfRides.addAll(objects);
                      mListener.onFindRideSucess();
                    } 
                  else 
                    {
                      mListener.onFindRideNoResults();
                    }
                 } 
               else 
                  {
                    Log.d(RoadPalApplication.TAG, "Find in background error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Log.d(RoadPalApplication.TAG, "getCause: ", e.getCause());
                    mListener.onFindRideFailure(e);
                 }
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat error:

```
01-02 19:11:44.453 1968-1968/? D/Road pal app: Find in background error :     i/o failure
01-02 19:11:44.453 1968-1968/? D/Road pal app: getCause: 
                                           java.io.IOException: unknown    format (magic number 227b)
                                               at       java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:101)
                                               at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
                                               at  com.parse.ParseDecompressInterceptor.intercept(ParseDecompressInterceptor.java:40)
                                               at  com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
                                               at  com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:115)
                                               at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
                                               at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.execute(ParseHttpClient.java:122)
                                               at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:135)
                                               at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:132)
                                               at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:839)
                                               at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
                                               at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:830)
                                               at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:642)
                                               at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:653)
                                               at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:745)
                                               at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:733)
                                               at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:839)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This eror happens if there are more than 2 RideModel results for current user and if emulator is with lower api than 21.
If i try it on emulator 5.0.0 v21 there are no errors and all objects are retrieved succesfully.
What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, "java.io.IOException: unknown format (magic number 227b)".

it will throw exception on my 4.2.2 device, but ok on 4.4.2 and 6.0 device.

now the parse's latest version is 1.12.0. seems fallback to 1.11.0 and re-install the app will stop the exception throwing, although I don't know the root cause of the exception

compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'

Comment: Found similar issue on: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/326

However, after few days of error described above now everything is working normally on all devices again. I am using latest version of Parse i guess:

          compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'    .Hope that error wont happen again.